# Sidebar Menu like on Myspace (for each profile)

Tags: 7, routes

I have several content types. Bio, images, videos etc. for each user.
Now i want to have sidebar menu like on Myspace profiles where the menu reacts only to user you are watching.

Is there a module for this or i should use views and how ?

Answer (score 0):

You might start with the [Author Pane](http://drupal.org/project/author_pane) module:

> Author Pane is a block of information about a given user, like those
>   typically found on a forum post, but can be used in other places as
>   well. From core, it collects the user picture, name, join date, online
>   status, contact link, and profile information. In addition, any module
>   or theme can feed it more information via the preprocess system. All
>   of this information is then gathered and displayed using a template
>   file.

Comment: So you think it can collect something that is not based on user profile ? like user/%/videos users/%/images ?